# Get OperationalError when uploading django project on pythonanywhere

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I'm just started working on django and created a simple django website,now want to deploy it on the pythonanywhere,after doing all the settings on the pythonanywhere

I found bellow errors,

OperationalError at /
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Here is my database settings,I'm using postgresql

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'sketch',
    'USER':'postgres',
    'PASSWORD':'1234',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':'5432'
}
```

}

here is settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ci0a_hv7_s_n#_=!)k+&qk(4#2kse-94r2fe7f^acr-*juocu6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['jaimajarnaz.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'drawings.apps.DrawingsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sketch.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/home/jaimajarnaz/sketch/static'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sketch.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'sketch',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'1234',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432'
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

]
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

I hope I'll find the solution here,please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Postgres server running on localhost for you to connect to.

If you have enabled Postgres for your account, then the details for the connection to your Postgres database are on your Databases tab. If you have not enabled Postgres for your account, then you can only connect to a Postgres server using the correct address for your postgres server (assuming you have a paid account).

Comment: Actually I don't have any paid account.

Comment: Free accounts on PythonAnywhere only have MySQL databases, not Postgres.  You can configure the free MySQL database on the "Databases" page, and then change your settings to use MySQL instead of Postgres.